# C - pcap_findalldevs to display all interfaces is stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, interface, pcap

I am working in C with pcap library and I am trying to create a function that would print all interfaces.

For that purpose I'm using pcap_findalldevs function, however when im trying to print the names and descriptions in a for loop, the printing goes on forever and prints only "any" for the name and "Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces" for the description.

code:

```
char errbuff[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
pcap_if_t *interface_list;

if(pcap_findalldevs(&interface_list, errbuff) == PCAP_ERROR){
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not list all interfaces: %s", errbuff);
    return ERR;
}

pcap_if_t *interface;
for(interface = interface_list; interface != NULL; interface = interface_list->next){
    printf("Name: %s (%s)\n",
           interface->name, interface->description);
}

pcap_freealldevs(interface_list);
```

Is there an error that I'm overlooking, or is this completely wrong?

Comment: Try running under `gdb`. Does `pcap_findalldevs` return? You print on error, but not success. Then, step through your loop. Right now, from what you've posted, we don't know who is getting stuck. The function or your loop. Your loop looks okay, so, I'd try to see if `pcap_findalldevs` returns. For reference, you could also compare against `ifconfig` et. al. output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "for" instruction, you are using "interface_list" instead of "interface" variable for accessing the "next" field.

The correct usage should be "for(interface = interface_list; interface != NULL; interface = ***interface***->next){"

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe i overlooked this.